# Запуск несколько приложений из своего приложения

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Я делаю наподобие лаунчера из своего приложения. У меня возникла потребность запустить после загрузки несколько сторонних приложений (на выбор пользователя). Использую такой код:

```
    for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        if (!app_name_start[j].equals("")) {
            Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app_package_start[j]);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(8000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Между запусками пауза в 8 секунд. Но запускается только первое приложение из списка. Да и проблема с возвратом на начальный экран. В эмуляторе работает всё нормально. На устройстве нет.

Подскажите, что не так? Как заставить запускать все выбранные приложения?

Comment: почитайте про Executors

Comment: @AzizUmarov, спасибо, сделал!

Comment: да тут не за что благодарить

Comment: @AzizUmarov при загрузке работает нормально, а вот после сна всё равно первая только программа запускается

Comment: так на словах диагностировать тяжко